# Can't load CCSpriteBatchNode using cocos2d when compiling in release mode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

Following is part of my program:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache *frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
NSString *plistFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", aName, @".plist"];
NSString *pngFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", aName, @".png"];

[frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:plistFileName textureFilename:pngFileName];
self.sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bandit_standby_1"];
self.batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:pngFileName];
```

The problem occurs in the last line:

```
self.batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:pngFileName];
```

When compiling in debug mode, nothing is wrong.

However, after changing mode to release, an error occurs:

> ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil

Can anyone tell me where is wrong?

Comment: Sounds like the pngFileName is not in the bundle. Verify that the file in question is included in the target/bundle.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D But in debug mode, how can it run correctly?